# Am I creating Valid WS-UsernameToken for ONVIF Authentication?

Tags: security, authentication, camera, video-streaming, onvif

I am writing an API for ONVIF authentication in C. I create WS-UsernameToken, But it is not working. Is there any problem with this WS-UsernameToken.

```
  unsigned int nonce_int = 0, i = 0;
  time_t utcTime = 0;
  struct tm *timeInfo = NULL;
  char sha1_input[100] = { 0 };
  SHA1Context sha = { 0 }; 

  nonce_int = GetRandomNumber();
  encode_base64(sizeof(nonce_int), (char*)&nonce_int, nonceLen, noncestr);

  utcTime = time(NULL);
  timeInfo = localtime(&utcTime);
  strftime(timestr, timeLen, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", timeInfo);
  sprintf(sha1_input, "%d%s%s", nonce_int, timestr, password);

  SHA1Reset(&sha);
  SHA1Input(&sha, (const unsigned char*)sha1_input, strlen(sha1_input));

  if(!SHA1Result(&sha))
  {
    printf("\nERROR-- could not compute message digest");
  }
  else
  {
    int i = 0;
    memset(sha1_input, 0x00, sizeof(sha1_input));

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      sha.Message_Digest[i] = ntohl(sha.Message_Digest[i]);
    }

   encode_base64(sizeof(sha.Message_Digest), (unsigned char*)sha.Message_Digest, digestLen, digeststr);        
  }

  return 0;
```

But when I use these values and send ONVIF request. It replies that "The security token could not be authenticated or authorized". I was wondering where I am making mistakes.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I was using local time string rather than utc time string. this solved my problem. thanks